# Query XML type data column and insert into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, parsing

Hoping someone can help me with a SQL Server issue, In one of our tables I have a longtext data type which contains data in an XML type format as below:

```
<entry name=\"cleaned_sectors\" type=\"uint\">585937500</entry>\r\n<entry name=\"bad_sectors\" type=\"uint\">0</entry>\r\n<entry name=\"state\"
```

Generally when I have come across XML in a table it looks like this:

```
<header>data</Header><Manufacturer>Dell</Manufacturer>
```

And I generate a query to obtain the data like so:

```
SELECT 
    Tbl.Col.value('Header[1], 'nvarchar(50)'), Tbl.Col.value('manufacturer[1].'nvarchar(50)') 
FROM ...
```

However you will notice this data isn't standard XML and each tag is contained using \" is there a way I can query the data contained with the aim to then import this into another table?

Expected output would be something like:

```
Cleaned Sectors | Bad Sectors
585937500       | 0
```

Any help with querying the data would be brilliant as I have been trying for hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your input like and then convert to XML and use as always.

```
SELECT
  CAST(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE('<entry name=\"cleaned_sectors\" type=\"uint\">585937500</entry>\r\n'
      ,'\"', '"')
   ,'\r\n', '')
  AS XML)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, could I use this method to effectively strip `<entry name=\"cleaned_sectors\" type=\"uint\">585937500</entry>\r\n` down to `<cleanedsectors>585937500</cleanedsectors>` or even just close the end tag with the element in the middle? `<cleanedsectors>585937500</>` and would this work to then query using my normal method?

Comment: works beautifully thank you so much - [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2730)